# Is it possible to map multiple rows inside a single entity?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations

I want to use a separate entity class to hold the relationship. However, I don't know what annotation I should put in the `StudentTest` class.

I've tried a few ways (eg. `ElementCollection`) but I got `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mainDB`. This error does not occur if I delete the `StudentTest` class.

Or is it not possible to use a `List` to hold the `Test` inside `StudentTest`?

These are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
public class Test {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "mark")
  private int mark;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_tests")
public class StudentTest {

  private Student student;

  private List<Test> test;

}
```

These are table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tests (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  mark INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_tests (
  student_id BIGINT(20),
  test_id BIGINT(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, test_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES tests(id)
);
```

UPDATE: I tried adding a composite Id with MapsId but it seems doesn't help

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_tests")
public class StudentTest {

  @EmbeddedId
  private StudentTestId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("studentId")
  private Student student;

  @OneToMany
  @MapsId("testId")
  private List<Test> test;
}

@Embeddable
public class StudentTestId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "student_id")
  private Long studentId;

  @Column(name = "test_id")
  private Long testId;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many

Comment: You don't present a "problem". What happens when you do what you say?!

Comment: @BillyFrost My problem is what annotation should be put in StudentTest class for the properties.

Comment: Why don't you look at any basic JPA tutorial then? They all tell you how to map relations in JPA. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html

Comment: I have some basic knowledge. I think my problem is having an entity for the association table, so I need Id to be on the OneToMany. At the same time, it is a composite key